# How to achieve greater accuracy in measuring distance using ARKit?

Tags: swift4, arkit, ios11.3

I have optimized [ARular](https://github.com/duzexu/ARuler) app according to my requirement. I have to calculate width of the objects in vertical planes.
Both apps (ARular and my modified app) calculates width of the object within close range (<10 feet) with minimum error percentage(1%-10%) but when I tried to measure the objects at long distance around 20-30 feet the error percentage is greater than 50% with both apps. There are minimum feature points at long distance but used to wait till I get feature points on the surface which I want to measure.

Is there any minimum distance for ARKit to work properly? Can anyone point me in right direction to achieve greater accuracy with long distance objects?

Comment: Would love to know whether you have (and how) been able to improve the accuracy? Thanks

Comment: I'm also stuck in same problem. Would like to know if you fine solution.

Comment: is there any update on this? I am also looking to calculate drift/ inaccuracy